# VS debugger doesn't load natstepfilter files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, step-into

I'm debugging applications that make heavy use of STL and in order not to be ramming Shift-F11 on the keyaboard whole day long I have a my.natstepfilter file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
  <Function><Name>std::.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
</StepFilter>
```

As far as I know this is the way to get VS2012 to not step into any function starting with `std::`, please correct me if I'm wrong.

This does not have any effect however, the debugger just jumps into everything.
Moreover when running procmon with a filter on `Visualizers` and starting a debug session, it looks like this:

[image]

So it querys everything in the correct directory, but then goes on reading all .natvis files but not the .natstepfilter files. So it seems VS is actively doing something to completely ignore the filters.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or where to look further for a solution?

Additional information: I have a whole bunch of extensions loaded but none of them seem to have any business at all with the debugger (let alone they'd tell VS to skip the filter files). Just to make sure the `Debugger Type` is set explicitly to `Native Only` as I read that the filters don't work for mixed mode. The application being debugged is native only though. Tried debugging both x86 and x64 processes.

Comment: Don't put it in the VS2010 directory.

Comment: @HansPassant got me there, I copied the wrong location. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The natstepfilter files are loaded(parsed) ONLY after first trying to StepInto.
New data viewing enhancements(natvis and natstepfilter) in the debugger introduced in Visual C++ 2012 do NOT work while EDIT AND CONTINUE (Tools->Options->Debugging->EditAndContinue) is turned on for native code.