# Why is my `.natstepfilter` file ignored by Visual Studio 2022 Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community and trying to make the debugger ignore some functions during the "Step Into" command. I have the following code in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void func(int x)
{
    std::cout << "func(" << x << ")\n";
}

void wrapper(int x)
{
    std::cout << "wrapper start" << "\n";
    func(x);
    std::cout << "wrapper end" << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    wrapper(10);
    wrapper(10);
}
```

and the following `my.natstepfilter` file in the same project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
    <Function>
        <Name>wrapper</Name>
        <Action>NoStepInto</Action>
    </Function>
</StepFilter>
```

based on examples [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019#BKMK_CPP_Customize_stepping_behavior). There was an announcement that [it's possible to have this file in a project since Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-natstepfilter-and-natjmc-to-be-i/561718#T-N10364299), not user-wide/system-wide.

However, the file seems to be completely ignored. The debugger steps into both `wrapper` and `func`, and there are no errors in its "Output" window.

I've also tried putting the `my.natstepfilter` file to user-wide and system-wide locations to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is [a very similar question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19563738/767632), but it explicitly excluded extensions in the question's text. Moreover, ReSharper C++ was [not publicly available in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999483/767632). I also think more details in my question will help someone else to debug their issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had the ReSharper C++ extension enabled, even though [it was suspended](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546999-How-can-I-temporary-disable-turn-off-ReSharper-) and not having any indexing or menu items.

[ReSharper is known](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2023.1/Reference_Options_Tools_Debugger_CPP.html) to disable `.natstepfilter` files completely:

> Note that at the moment Visual Studio’s support for `.natstepfilter` files gets disabled if ReSharper C++ is installed.

#### Solution

There is no need to actually *uninstall* ReSharper, it's enough to fully disable the extension in the `Extensions > Manage Extensions` menu by clicking the `Disable` button next to it and restarting Visual Studio:

[image: Screenshot of the "Manage Extensions" window, the "Disable" button is marked in the right part of the "JetBrains ReSharper 2023.1.3" row]

#### Workaround 1

You can also use ReSharper's own debugging step filters described [on the same page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2023.1/Reference_Options_Tools_Debugger_CPP.html): add a filter either by pressing Alt+Enter immediately after stepping into the `wrapper` function, or under by added `^wrapper$` in ReSharper's Options `Tools > Debugger > C++`, `Step filters` on the right. It will work exactly like `my.natstepfilter`.

[image: Screenshot of ReSharper's Options window with the list of step filters and ^wrapper$ filter selected]

#### Workaround 2

Another option is to use [`.natjmc` (Just My Code) files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019#BKMK_CPP_Customize_call_stack_behavior) instead. They do not prevent the debugger from entering the `wrapper` function completely, but they mark it as "External Code" so it becomes transparent for the debugger: stepping into the `wrapper` function will actually step into the `func` directly. That may even be better depending on your goal.

Here is an example `my.natjmc` that you can add into the project, it works even with ReSharper C++ enabled:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NonUserCode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/jmc/2015">
  <Function Name="wrapper" />
</NonUserCode>
```

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Ah, yes, thank you. Forgot about that post already and I cannot mark my own answer in the first two days, so it was left like this.